# How to increase div height to match the height of next div?

Tags: html, css

I want to get a page with a header and a menu and content areas.

This is my code.

**HTML**:

```
<div class="header">Title</div>
<div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li>option 1</li>
        <li>second option</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="content">
    <h1>ASDUAHSD ASDASD ASID AS DAKSH</h1>
    <h1>ASDUAHSD ASDASD ASID AS DAKSH</h1>
    <h1>ASDUAHSD ASDASD ASID AS DAKSH</h1>
    <h1>ASDUAHSD ASDASD ASID AS DAKSH</h1>
    <h1>ASDUAHSD ASDASD ASID AS DAKSH</h1>
    <h1>ASDUAHSD ASDASD ASID AS DAKSH</h1>
    <h1>ASDUAHSD ASDASD ASID AS DAKSH</h1>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.header {
    background-color: yellow;
    padding: 10px;
}

.menu {
    background-color: blue;
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
}

.content {
    background-color: red;
    float: left;
    width: 80%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/x1q03qfk/

As you can see in the jsfiddle, **.menu** is shorter than **.content**, but I want it to take the same height of **.content**.

If I replace the **float:left** by **display: table-cell** it works but I want to avoid that solution.

I also tried  position: absolute on **.menu** and **top:0**, **bottom:0** but with no luck.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried using min-height to force the menu to a minimum height that matches the height of the content div?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the DOM loads just set the height of menu to be the same as content:

Here is an example using **jQuery**:

```
$(".menu").height($(".content").height());
```

Here is an example using **Native JS**:

```
var contentHeight = document.getElementsByClassName("content")[0].clientHeight;
document.getElementsByClassName("menu")[0].style.height = contentHeight+"px";
```

Comment: thanks Spencer, I already tried something like this but if .content increases its height, .menu keeps the old height

Comment: @Boel Then you just need to do this when the height of the element changes as well.

Comment: I assumed that your content is always taller than menu, otherwise it won't work as expected, demo - http://jsfiddle.net/gbawqfep/

Comment: @sdcr Yes I did assume that, although it's an overflow issue. An easy fix is to add some [`overflow-y` CSS to the menu](http://jsfiddle.net/gbawqfep/1/).

Answer (score 2):

Just use the correct markup

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}
body {
  margin: 0
}
.header {
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 10px;
}
.menu {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 20vw;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 100%
}
.content {
  background-color: red;
  float: right;
  width: 80vw;
  position: relative
}
```

```html
<div class="header">Title</div>

<div class="content">
  <div class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li>option 1</li>
      <li>second option</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <h1>ASDUAHSD ASDASD ASID AS DAKSH</h1>
  <h1>ASDUAHSD ASDASD ASID AS DAKSH</h1>
  <h1>ASDUAHSD ASDASD ASID AS DAKSH</h1>
  <h1>ASDUAHSD ASDASD ASID AS DAKSH</h1>
  <h1>ASDUAHSD ASDASD ASID AS DAKSH</h1>
  <h1>ASDUAHSD ASDASD ASID AS DAKSH</h1>
  <h1>ASDUAHSD ASDASD ASID AS DAKSH</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried (for example) something like:

```
.menu {
background-color: blue;
float: left;
width: 20%;
min-height: 437px;
```

}

Comment: ( of course, this uses a fixed height, which is probably not what you were looking for )

Answer (score 1):

There is a modern way to do it with **[`flexbox`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)**.

```css
.header {
    background-color: silver;
    padding: 10px;
}
.main {
    display: flex; /*this is the magic one*/
}
.menu {
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 20%;
}
.content {
    background-color: gold;
    width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">Title</div>
<div class="main">
    <div class="menu">
        <ul>
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 2</li>
            <li>Item 3</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
         <h1>Hello World</h1>
        <p>Ennui literally art party, selfies iPhone exercitation try-hard commodo twee reprehenderit nihil irure Echo Park pour-over kitsch. Beard Intelligentsia locavore mixtape, odio aesthetic hella listicle seitan organic vinyl. Ennui exercitation deserunt tousled four dollar toast, ad pop-up vegan wolf minim whatever dreamcatcher.</p>
        <p>Ennui literally art party, selfies iPhone exercitation try-hard commodo twee reprehenderit nihil irure Echo Park pour-over kitsch. Beard Intelligentsia locavore mixtape, odio aesthetic hella listicle seitan organic vinyl. Ennui exercitation deserunt tousled four dollar toast, ad pop-up vegan wolf minim whatever dreamcatcher.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I believe `table` + `table-cell` is a better choice if you want it to work on all major browsers.

```css
.header {
    background-color: silver;
    padding: 10px;
}
.main {
    display: table;
}
.menu, .content {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.menu {
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 20%;
}
.content {
    background-color: gold;
    width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">Title</div>
<div class="main">
    <div class="menu">
        <ul>
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 2</li>
            <li>Item 3</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
         <h1>Hello World</h1>
        <p>Ennui literally art party, selfies iPhone exercitation try-hard commodo twee reprehenderit nihil irure Echo Park pour-over kitsch. Beard Intelligentsia locavore mixtape, odio aesthetic hella listicle seitan organic vinyl. Ennui exercitation deserunt tousled four dollar toast, ad pop-up vegan wolf minim whatever dreamcatcher.</p>
        <p>Ennui literally art party, selfies iPhone exercitation try-hard commodo twee reprehenderit nihil irure Echo Park pour-over kitsch. Beard Intelligentsia locavore mixtape, odio aesthetic hella listicle seitan organic vinyl. Ennui exercitation deserunt tousled four dollar toast, ad pop-up vegan wolf minim whatever dreamcatcher.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```